# Get a List of Apps which can create a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-package-managers

I think the question says it all: How can I get a list of apps which can create a notification. I can get a list of all apps with this code:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

but there are system apps and so on. How can I only get the apps which can create a notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Notification is not exposed in Manifest, so you cannot see that without reverse engeneering.